# Angular - service workers causing uploads to fail

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

My angular 6 app uses Uppy (XHRUpload) for file uploads. File uploads happen to a different subdomain.

The uploads work fine on localhost (with service worker disabled), but when I try to upload files with service worker enabled it only works for files of small size (few mb's) and fails for others.

It seems like service worker waits for the response of API upload call and if it doesn't return within few seconds (for large files) it fails as I can see in the developer tools.

Following is my ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
          "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to exclude that path to be cached/handled by service worker.

Either in `ngsw-config.json` put the route to ["navigationUrls"](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#navigationurls).

Or, if you can, put the file upload API endpoint to route that starts with (or has) `__` (that is double underscore) in the path. By default angular service worker should treat this as `navigationUrl`, this is what is generated in `ngsw.json`:

```
  "navigationUrls": [
{
  "positive": true,
  "regex": "^\\/.*$"
},
{
  "positive": false,
  "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
},
{
  "positive": false,
  "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
},
{
  "positive": false,
  "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
}
]
```